# I can seem to figure out why I am getting syntax error. Any ideas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

We are building a dynamic SELECT box with autocomplete to be modeled after the Standard Select on this link:

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

The SELECT box wasn't populating.

It turns out that the SELECT plugin on that link does not support Ajax itself.

Now, I am trying a workaround by trying to recreate the `<options>...</options>` each time we wanted to add options.

But it is still not populating.

I ran it in console and it says syntax error on line 96 here:

```
).each(function(i, building) {
  $('<option>')
    .val(building.BuildingID)
    .text(building.BuildingDisplay)
    .appendTo($('#buildingID'));
```

Could someone please try to see if you can find what I am doing wrong?

Here is the entire (necessary) code:

```
function getBuildings() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'getBuildings.php',
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .done(function(buildingInfo) {
   $(buildingInfo).replaceWith('<select name="buildingID" id="buildingID" style="width:600px;font-size:10pt;" class="changeable" data-summary="summBuilding"></select>')
      ).each(function(i, building) {
    $('<option>').val(building.BuildingID).text(building.BuildingDisplay).appendTo( $('#buildingID') );
   })

  $("#buildingID").choose();
  });
 }
```

The SELECT box:

```
<div>
  <select name="buildingID" id="buildingID" data-placeholder="Choose a building..." class="chosen-select" style="width:500px;">
    <option value=""></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help in advance

```
    function getBuildings() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getBuildings.php',
            dataType: 'json'
        })
  .done(function(buildingInfo) {
$(buildingInfo).replaceWith('<select name="buildingID" id="buildingID" style="width:600px;font-size:10pt;" class="changeable" data-summary="summBuilding"></select>')).each(function(i, building) {$('<option>').val(building.BuildingID).text(building.BuildingDisplay).appendTo( $('#buildingID')}) );
   })

  $("#buildingID").choose();
  });
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please use http://jshint.com/ or http://jslint.com for detecting and finding simpler syntax (and style) errors before posting on SO.

The error appears to be an extra bracket here:

```
.replaceWith('stuff')).each(function(i, building) {})
```

As per request here's the (syntax-ally) corrected code:

```
function getBuildings() {
    $.ajax({
        url     : 'phpservices/getBuildings.php',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (buildingInfo) {
        $(buildingInfo)//wrap json in jquery
          .replaceWith('<select name="buildingID" id="buildingID" style="width:600px;font-size:10pt;" class="changeable" data-summary="summBuilding"></select>')//replace json with select which is never added to the dom
          .each(function (i, building) { //iterate the select ***NOT THE JSON BECAUSE YOU REPLACED IT***
              $('<option>')
                .val(building.BuildingID)
                .text(building.BuildingDisplay)
                .appendTo($('#buildingID'));
          });
          $("#buildingID").choose();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot.

I put together what I understood to be your recommendation but still no luck. It is possible I still missed something. Could you please put entire code together?

BTW: I tried the link and I will need a bit more time to process it.

Comment: thanks again.

Obviously, something is going on. It is still not populating.

Please see screenshot above. Top one shows that the SELECT works if options are populated statically to the SELECT box.

The bottom part of the screen shows blank <SELECT> when you attempt to click to open the SELECT box

Comment: I'll throw in some comments to point out some logic errors. You should create the select and append it to the dom outside of that chain. Will also allow you to reduce the `$("#buildingID")` all over the place

Comment: I really appreciate very much your help and your time but if these guys continue to mark this question down and keep deducting points, I will have to delete it.

I hope that you get to keep the points you have earned.

I have such difficult time understanding why they would continue to mark questions down, largely because they don't understand the question, can't help with the answer but very subjectively critical.

Comment: I haven't marked you down but the reason they're marking you down is probably that this answer or your question are unlikely to help anyone else in the future as its a code specific syntax error + some logic.